# Python Lambda not recognizing Layer Libraries

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to support the usage of external libraries in my python3.8 lambda. I found that Python layers is a good way to do this.

One of the libraries I need to import is selenium. Currently, when I invoke my lambda (the file name is "batchscheduler"), I am receiving the following output:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'batchscheduler': No module named 'selenium'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Here is the `batchscheduler.py`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Hello!")
```

To make sure that there was a `python/` directory, I downloaded the Lambda function and saw the following project structure, which appears correct:

[image]

Furthermore, expanding the `python` folder, I see that `selenium` is in fact there:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the version of python from inside your python directory or are you using an alternate installation?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure that I understand the question. The modules were installed to the `python` folder through `pip install <modulename> -t python/`. I verified that my pip version corresponded to Python 3.8. The lambda runtime is set to Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. It was pretty dumb of me.

I have never worked with Layers. When I saw the `python` folder in the Lambda code on the AWS Console, I assumed it was there on part of the layer. It was not.

The `python` folder was mistakenly included in the lambda function code payload, which is why it was there when I exported the lambda function.

Additionally, after exporting the broken layer, I saw this was the structure:

[image]

This is not what a Python layer should look like when exported. These folders should all be subfolders of the `python` folder instead.

I removed the `python` folder from being a member of the lambda code payload. Further, I ensured that the layer .zip had a single member, `python`, wherein the modules were stored.